# Google Autocomplete HTMLInputElement error

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am using Google Autocomplete and am getting this error

```
InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement
```

I think Google has getElementById for deprication

```
var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
  document.getElementById('pac-input'));
```

However i'm unsure on it's usage. My code below

```
var options ={
    types:['(cities)'],
};

var input = document.getElementById('destination');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `onFocus="functionName()"` which calls `google.maps.autocomplete` on input tag.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and it worked using this

```
  let searchInputField = document.getElementsByClassName('search-form')[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]

  let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchInputField);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as why the OP's code does not work and your works.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the element it returns an array, so:

```
    const memberPlace = $("#place");
    const memberAddress = $("#address");
    const options = {
        fields: ["address_components", "geometry", "icon", "name"],
        strictBounds: false,
        types: ["establishment"],
    };

    if (memberPlace.length) {
        new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(memberPlace[0], options);
    }

    if (memberAddress.length) {
        new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(memberAddress[0], options);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

check if the your function is in $(document).ready function or your document.getElementById won't be found by js (cos it tries to find it before it appears in document)

Answer (score -2):

It's because you overwrite your input variable. Should work if you just use var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
  document.getElementById('pac-input')); or replace "pac-input" with "destination"